# How to deal with a different format in a specific tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to be able to individually deal with some tags in a HTML file. My code is working ok (so far) for all tags except for two. These two have two lines each instead of one. Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("F:/gpu.txt") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    section = soup.find_all("td")
    #print(section[2])
    for section in section:
        if section.parent(text="GPU Name:"):
            print(section.text)
        elif section.parent(text="GPU Variant:"):
            print (section.text)
        elif section.parent(text="Bus Interface:"):
            print (section.text)
        elif section.parent(text="Transistors:"):
            print (section.text)
```

And it goes on. However, when we get to, let's say "Process Size:", the html code is different:

```
        <th>Process Size:</th>
      <td>
        Something 
                <br />
                Something Else
              </td>
    </tr>
```

When for all other cases, it's like:

```
      <th>GPU Name:</th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <th>GPU Variant:</th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <th>Bus Interface:</th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Transistors:</th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
```

So when i run my script, I get the following results:

```
BLABLA
BLABLA

        Something 

                Something Else

BLABLA
BLABLA
```

What I need is to be able to work with "Something" and "Something Else" individually (and without those white line and white spaces) and/or make it one thing only, to transform it into a string like: "Something / Something Else".

Sorry if my message isn't clear enough, english isn't my first language. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all text nodes (using [`text=True`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument)) inside a section and join them with `/`:

```
print('/'.join(item.strip() for item in section.find_all(text=True)))
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>GPU Name:</th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <th>GPU Variant:</th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <th>Process Size: </th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Transistors:</th>
      <td>BLABLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Process Size:</th>
      <td>
        Something
                <br />
                Something Else
              </td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
section = soup.find_all("td")

for section in section:
    if section.parent(text="GPU Name:"):
        print(section.text)
    elif section.parent(text="GPU Variant:"):
        print (section.text)
    elif section.parent(text="Process Size:"):
        print ('/'.join(item.strip() for item in section.find_all(text=True)))
    elif section.parent(text="Transistors:"):
        print (section.text)
```

Prints:

```
BLABLA
BLABLA
BLABLA
Something/Something Else
```

Answer (score 0):

This is highly specific to your sample HTML and it relies on the existence of newline characters, but you could do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("F:/gpu.txt") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    for section in soup.find_all("td"):
        print '/'.join([s.strip() for s in section.text.split('\n') if s.strip()])
```